# Office Add-in with method that requires Excel JS API 1.9 runs on Office 2016. How is this possible?

Tags: excel, office-js, office-addins, excel-addins

I have made an Office JS Addin that makes use of

```
copyFrom(sourceRange: Range | RangeAreas | string, copyType?: Excel.RangeCopyType, skipBlanks?: boolean, transpose?: boolean): void;
```

This method requires Excel JS API 1.9 so it is supported on Office 365 according to documentation. Also, my Addin makes use of other methods that require Excel JS API > 1.1.
I am wondering how it is possible for my Addin to be fully functional in Office 2016 which supports only up to Excel JS API 1.1 . Keep in mind that I have no runtime checks using the isSetSupported() method.
I would expect my Addin to be functional only on Office 365. Does it make sense to you? Am I missing something?

Comment: this runtime check : if (Office.context.requirements.isSetSupported('ExcelApi', '1.9'))  returns true, in my Office 2016 - 2011 version, Build 13426 . Does it make sense? According to docs, Office 2016 supports only Excel Js API 1.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Builds 16.0.13426.XXXXX is actually a Monthly Subscription build. At the time of this writing is actually the latest publicly available Office version in Production. Hence 1.9 will be supported along with the copyFrom API.

Comment: So  the last build for Office 2016 MS has released, supports Excel JS API even higher than 1.9, like 1.11 - 1.12 ?

Comment: The build that you cited is a monthly subscription build. There is a different licensing (known as MSI) that do not get the M365 updates. That's not your case.